# Connecting MATLAB to TFS Preview

Tags: matlab, tfs

is there a way to connect MATLAB with TFS Preview? I installed the MSSCCI interface, but when I'm about to connect to the server, I received an error. Something very general like "Cannot make a connection, an error has occured"
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it requires Visual Studio 2012 and a beta MSSCCI provider (see [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35a37fd5-3385-4f2e-8f4e-36ccbabb1a8e))

Another option is to use MATLAB with a local git repository and then use git-tf (see [here](http://gittf.codeplex.com/)) to connect your local git repo with your tfspreview account.